# Android NDK static library debugging (merge projects?)

Tags: android, eclipse, android-ndk, static-libraries

I am looking for a better way to debug a large project I am working on that has a very large NDK core. The NDK code consists of a large C/C++ static library that is built and then linked through NDK code to the main android application. The NDK portion of the project is itself also in an android library project. So in total that makes three projects (Android -> NDK glue project -> Native C lib)

It is my understanding that NDK debugging works poorly (or not at all) when attempting to interface with a library project. I suspect I could merge the NDK glue code project with the main android project with relatively little pain, but the bigger problem is the C/C++ project that contains the core of the project.

Is there a feasible way to merge a C/C++ project and an android NDK project without having to rewrite the build/make scripts for the C++/C project?

The current build scripts for the static library are quite complicated and will probably be quite difficult to convert to Android.mk files.

Are there any better ways to do this that I have not considered?

Comment: I'm a little confused by how you're referring to the "NDK portion" vs the "C/C++" portion. Both have to be built with the NDK into shared or static libraries -- And ultimately, you can only load a native SO from Android (via the Java side) and access methods from Java through JNI (again, in your SO with C-style exports). You should be able to link everything into one mega.so and use/debug it.

Comment: The "NDK portion" of the code is specifically referring to the glue code used to connect the C/C++ library to the java code using JNI. This is currently a separate library project from the main Android application that references it. The C/C++ library it references has a very complicated build structure (including some build time generated code) and has to be built from the console outside of the NDK project. This makes it difficult to trace through using the eclipse environment. In the end there is one SO file, but eclipse can only debug into the C/C++ code that is in the NDK glue project.

Comment: Without knowing more, it sounds like either the library portion needs debug information enabled and/or Eclipse needs to know additional path(s) to debug object files and source.

Comment: It is possible to ndk-build several modules from the same android mk file. What do your make scripts do? How did you manage to build an android .so without ndk-build? I did use a 2-phase build scheme: first a build script patched the source code and mk files, and then ndk-build was invoked to build the stuff.